# mvn package error

Tags: java, maven

I am new to the networking java, I need to build network discovery using `snmp` using java. I started looking into netTransformer code build from this link: "https://github.com/iTransformers/netTransformer"

But when I do cd nettransformer, mvn package I throws following error:

> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> [INFO] Total time: 2.183 s
>
> [INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-21T08:57:25+05:30
>
> [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/17M
>
> ### [INFO]
>
> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or
>   one of its   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read
>   artifact descriptor for org. 
>   apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to
>   central (https:  //repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to
>   localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1]   failed: Connection refused:
>   connect -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
>   the -e swit ch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR]

Please help me in solving the above issue, I have tried tried several solutions it didn't solved.

Comment: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused. Do you use a proxy, or any server on localhost:8080? Make sure it works

Comment: Hi ,I was using maven 3.3 now I changed to maven 2.2.1 now I am getting below error as    Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin

Reason: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin' not found in repository
: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:pom:3.1

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  iTransformers Repo (http://repo.itransformers.net/repos)

 for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin

Comment: And I don't see any proxy server set in my system.Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Check for a proxy in Control Panel/Java Control Panel settings.

It should be located under the Network Settings. 
Note that the java proxy is different from the one configured in your browser.